# solving merge conflict in vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

The `vs-code` has an amazing feature to solve merge conflicts as shown in the image..

[image: image source google]

We can easily select `current`,`incoming` or `both` the changes..
but in case of `vim` we have to manually do it which becomes problematic when file size is large...is there any nice way to do this in `vim?`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are not clear in your question:

1. How do you "select current, incoming or both"? Mouse click?
2. What do you find problematic with Vim, exactly?

Anyway, here is how a basic merge conflict resolution looks after:

```
$ git mergetool --tool vimdiff
```

[image: Three-way merge in Vim]

- The top-left window, called "LOCAL", shows the file as it is in the branch you are merging to. This is what's called "current" in your screenshot.
- The top-right window, called "REMOTE", shows the file as it is in the branch you are merging from. This is what's called "incoming" in your screenshot.
- The top-center window, called "BASE", shows the file as it was before any of the above changes. I can't see it in your screenshot.
- The bottom window shows the file in its current state, with conflict markers. This is the equivalent of your current view. Except you don't have to edit conflict markers.

Usage is pretty simple:

- to jump to next change (not "conflict"), press `]c`, and `[c` for the previous change,
- to choose LOCAL change, do `:diffget LOCAL` (or `:diffg L` for short),
- to choose BASE change, do `:diffg B`,
- to choose REMOTE change, do `:diffg R`,
- to choose both change, remove the conflict markers, as there's no built-in command for that.

If you still find it too "manual" you can simply make your own mapping:

```
" choose LOCAL
nnoremap <Left> :diffget LOCAL<Bar>diffupdate<CR>
" choose REMOTE
nnoremap <Right> :diffget REMOTE<Bar>diffupdate<CR>
" choose BASE
nnoremap <Up> :diffget BASE<Bar>diffupdate<CR>
" choose both
nnoremap <Down> :/>>>>>>>/;?<<<<<<<?,.g/^\(<<<<<<<\\|=======\\|>>>>>>>\)/d<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

My [ConflictMotions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3991) has motions to go to the next conflict [marker] (`]x`, `]=`), corresponding text objects, and also a `:ConflictTake` command that lets you resolve the conflict by choosing some of the parts (`[none this ours base theirs both all range query]`).

Comment: Hello from the future! I know there’s a fancier way of doing things with fugitive (which I also use) but for merges this is exactly what I need. Thanks!